# Show notification in Android 5.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

I want to create a Notification in my Android App, but my code doesn't work!

```
NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification.Builder nBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
nBuilder.setContentTitle("Title...");
nBuilder.setContentText("Text...");
nBuilder.setContentInfo("Info?");
nBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

//Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//PendingIntent pendingIntent = new PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

nManager.notify(noti_ID, nBuilder.build());
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Help us help you. What exactly "doesn't work" mean? What did you expect  to see that is not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

> **Required notification contents**
>
> A Notification object *must* contain the following:
>
> **A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()**
> A title, set by setContentTitle()
> Detail text, set by setContentText()

So set a small icon too.